# Visual Studio 2010 - Macro menu disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My VS2010 Macros menu has been disabled. Any ideas on how to get it back?

[image: Macros menu gone!]

Comment: Never new there was one! Great regexp find-replace though, even in my lowly Express one.

Comment: @x2 Nopes, full version.

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Options->Environment->Add-in/Macros Security->Enable Allow macros to run

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not available in VS 2010 Express - which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Premium, and i'm pretty sure they were enabled the last time i needed them.